# Vertically gradient color on RecyclerView items like Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml

How is it possible to apply vertically gradient color to `RecyclerView` items so that the color of the items changes when scrolling? Does Facebook Messenger update all items when scrolling?

[image: Example]

Comment: Maybe gradient color is on the background and every message backgraound is transprant

Comment: Do you mean the background of the chat activity? But it is white

Comment: the Window could be white, but they maybe apply a LinearGradient  using the screen size as the source. I recall these gradients did fancy (unintended?) effects when applied like so (via canvas) since they are kinda lower level than the theme system.